# Confirming Group-Requests with Facebook Open Graph

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Every day we have a lot of group requests and we want to confirm requests individually and automatically. Is there a way to do this?

At the docs I found some informations about inviting, but not about confirming members for a private group:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/group/members

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to accept/decline group requests with the API. Also, inviting is only possible for Groups created by an App (App/Game Group).